# when accessing the stack frame like this <dword ptr [ebp-8]>, is it considered popped?

Tags: assembly, masm

I found this assembly code and while analyzing it, I realized that I see no cleaning or balancing of the stack here. And I thought that maybe accessing the stack like `dword ptr [ebp-8]` is equivalent to popping the content. Am I correct, if no, then why is it that the code below shows no `pop` instruction or `add esp, whatever` ??

```
_AddMe:
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
sub esp, 0ch
mov eax, dword ptr [ebp+0ch]
mov dword ptr [ebp-4], eax
mov eax, dword ptr [ebp+8]
mov dword ptr [ebp-8], eax
mov eax, dword ptr [ebp-8]
add eax, dword ptr [ebp-4]
mov dword ptr [ebp-0ch], eax
mov eax, dword ptr [ebp-0ch]
jmp AddMeEpilogue
AddMeEpilogue:
mov esp, ebp
pop ebp
ret
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can increment and decrement the stack pointer manually, so adding/subtracting to esp is basically similar to push and pop operation.

**Example**

```
mov eax, 2134
push eax
mov ebx, [esp]
add esp, 04    <-- This is the actual pop operation.
mov ecx, [esp-4]
ret
```

You can see that I don't do a pop after the push, but the code still executes correct and is similar to.

```
push eax
pop ebx
mov ecx, ebx
```

Accessing the stack doesn't change the correctness of it. So if you do a `mov eax, dword ptr [ebp-0ch]` doesn't mean that the stack will be correct or incorrect, because it just fetches some value from memory which happens to be the stack. Only increasing or decreasing the ESP has a meaning that can be considered as `push` or `pop` operation.

Comment: yes. but by doing this, mov eax, dword ptr [ebp-0ch], does it mean, the value at ebp 0CH is already popped?

Comment: I updated my answer with an example, I hope this makes it clearer for you. Only if you change ESP you can say it has an effect as if pushed or popped.

Answer (score 4):

`EBP` is saved on the stack upon entering the function, and is then set to point to the current top of the stack (`mov ebp,esp`).

Some space for local variables is then allocated on the stack by moving the stack pointer downward (`sub esp,0ch`). The data in that area is then referenced using `EBP` *minus* an offset (since `EBP` equals `ESP` *before* the subtraction).

The function arguments meanwhile are accessed using `EBP` *plus* an offset.

Before the function returns it restores `ESP` and `EBP` (`mov esp,ebp` sets `ESP` to the value it had right after the `push ebp` at the beginning of the function).